# Cassandra integration with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, nosql, hive, integration

I am newbie to Cassandra. I am posting this question as different documentations were providing different details with respect to integeting  Hive with Cassandra and I was not able to find the github page.

I have installed a single node Cassandra 2.0.2 (Datastax Community Edition) in one of the data nodes of my 3 node HDP 2.0 cluster.

I am unable to use hive to access Cassandra using 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.CqlStorageHandler'. I am getting the error ' return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.CqlStorageHandler'

I have copied all the jars in  /$cassandra_home/lib/* to /$hive-home/lib and also included the /cassandra_home/lib/* in the $HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

Is there any other configuration changes that I have to make to integrate Cassandra with Hadoop/Hive?

Please let me know. Thanks for the help!

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Probably these are starting points for you:

- [Hive support for Cassandra, github](https://github.com/milliondreams/hive.git)
- [Top level article related to your topic with general information: Hive support for Cassandra CQL3.](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/post/hive-support-for-cassandra-cql3)
- [Hadoop support, Cassandra Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport).

Actually your question is not so narrow, there could be lot of reasons for this. But what you should remember Hive is based on MapReduce engine.

Hope this helps.